# Почему прерывается установка пакетa в Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, apt

начал установку

```
~$ sudo apt install git
Reading package lists... Done
```

в результате выдает нижний текст

> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

повторил несколько раз, результат - одинаковый...

Comment: программа *apt* «падает». что-то в системе поломано. начиная с оперативной памяти и до бесконечности.

Comment: alexander barakin. Если проблемы не технические, можно ли как нибудь исправить на системном уровне?

Comment: судя по первым же результатам запроса `apt core dumped`, чего-то там опять убунтушники наломали. рекомендуют снести пакет `libappstream3`: `$ sudo dpkg -P libappstream3` (циферка у вас может и отличаться).

Comment: а для чего этот пакет? Если удалю, какие будут последствия?

Comment: ну, прочитайте его описание: `$ apt-cache show имя-пакета`. // если от него чего-то зависит, *dpkg* откажется удалять. тогда попробуйте всё-таки *apt-ом/apt-get-ом*, чтобы и зависящие пакеты удалились: `$ sudo apt purge libappstream3` (если пол-системы предложит снести, то, наверно, лучше пока не стоит).

Comment: ничего себе..... удалил, установка прошла успешно. Большой, жирный +++++ вашему ответу, и, конечно же, СПАСИБО!!!

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77377/discussion-between-hovhannes-shaxulyan-and-alexander-barakin).

Answer (score 2):

судя по содержимому [относительно свежей ссылки](https://askubuntu.com/q/1014608/416190), которую первой выдаёт google на запрос `apt core dumped`, надо удалить пакет `libappstream3`:

```
$ sudo apt purge libappstream3
```

и повторить попытку установки нужного пакета.